# YouTube API and Complex Search

Tags: api, search, youtube

I'd like to make a complex YouTube search for the videos. I couldn't do it with YouTube's search operators, so I think the only way to do it is through YouTube API.

How would you write it in javascript (or anything else):

Find videos:

1. with the keywords: 'puppies', 'dogs'
2. videos have to be uploaded today
3. authors of the found videos started their YouTube channel today

All three conditions have to be true. This third condition is what makes it difficult for me. I cannot find the way to create the search which would fulfill all three conditions. Any idea how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for first two criteria seems easy, like issue search with keyword filter plus 'orderby=published'. Then you simply walk trough list and stop after publishing date goes before today or list ends.

I read a lot about YouTube API and did not see anything like 3rd criteria.

You probably could issue separate request for each unique author and see 1st video uploaded by each of them and that could be near your requirements.